# Error in installing Puppeteer - SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN on AWS workspace

Tags: puppeteer

Getting the following error while installing puppeteer. the machine is AWS workspace and I have already setup the certificate file in npmrc

`D:\git>npm install puppeteer`

`> puppeteer@3.0.0 install D:\git\node_modules\puppeteer`
`> node install.js`

`ERROR: Failed to set up Chromium r737027! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.`
`Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain`
`at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1321:34)`
`at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)`
`at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:794:8)`
`at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:608:12)`
`-- ASYNC --`
`at BrowserFetcher.<anonymous> (D:\git\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\helper.js:105:23)`
`at fetchBinary (D:\git\node_modules\puppeteer\install.js:150:27)`
`at download (D:\git\node_modules\puppeteer\install.js:78:9) {`
`code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'`
`}`

Answer (score 3):

You can disabled certificate validation for TLS connections:

```
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 npm install puppeteer
```

Comment: I've tried all sorts of different answers but this is the one that worked for me.  Thanks!

Comment: This is kinda bad because you avoid SSL certificate checks that can lead to potential security risks.

Answer (score 3):

At the CMD prompt type:

```
set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
npm install puppeteer
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Just be sure to run `set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=1` afterwards, ha.

Answer (score 1):

If you use maven (frontend-maven-plugin) the only solution that works for me
is:

```
<execution>
    <id>npm install</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>npm</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <environmentVariables>
        <PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD>true</PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD>
        </environmentVariables>
        <arguments>install --@rgi:registry=${npm.registry.url}</arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```